# Replace characters in filename through .bat

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a file named - for example: `01_XXXXXXXX_XXXX_XXX.txt`.

I need to strip out the first three characters (replace `01_` by nothing) and replace the remaining `_` by <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>.

I cannot use PowerShell, I do need to have a simple `.bat`file, to loop through all files in the directory where it is present, and do this task.

So I am using this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*_*) do (
  set file=%%a
  ren "!file!" "!file:_= !"
)

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set X=2
for %%f in (*) do if %%f neq %~nx0 (
    set "filename=%%~nf"
    set "filename=!filename:~%X%,-%X%!"
    ren "%%f" "!filename!%%~xf"
)
popd
```

But it is eating two characters at the end before the extension and adding a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> at the beginning.

Any idea why?

Comment: Yup it is :) Google search how to trim the first x characters of a string in batch and then google search string replacement in batch :) For the looping check `For /?`.

Comment: Just as an aside, why have you got two `@echo off` and two `setlocal` statements in the same file, and a `popd` without a `pushd`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are splitting off the first two and the last two characters, as you implemented the [sub-string expansion syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) wrongly. The leading <kbd>SPACE</kbd> derives from the first `_` before the replacements.

The following shows a reliable way of doing it, using a single loop and [sub-string replacement syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) only, the first time with the `*` immediately after the `:`, telling the command line interpreter to replace everything up to and including the first occurrence of the search string:

```bat
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for %%A in ("*_*") do (
    rem // Store current item:
    set "FILE=%%~A"
    rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid loss of or trouble with `!`:
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Remove everything up to and including the first `_`:
    set "FNEW=!FILE:*_=!"
    rem // Replace every remaining `_` by ` `:
    ren "!FILE!" "!FNEW:_= !"
    endlocal
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

Answer (score 1):

If your pattern is consistent with `01_XXXXXXXX_XXXX_XXX.txt` *(i.e. an unrequired string ending with `_` followed by three required strings separated by `_`)*, then a one liner like this may suffice:

From a batch file:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=1-4 Delims=_" %%A In ('Where ?*_?*_?*_?*.txt') Do @If Not Exist "%%B %%C %%D" @Ren "%%A_%%B_%%C_%%D" "%%B %%C %%D"
```

From the command prompt:

```bat
For /F "Tokens=1-4 Delims=_" %A In ('Where ?*_?*_?*_?*.txt') Do @If Not Exist "%B %C %D" @Ren "%A_%B_%C_%D" "%B %C %D"
```